# Last buttons in a row is missing

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a jquery loop where it displays buttons A - Z but what it does is display 7 buttons in a row. So it should look like this below:

```
    A B C D E F G
    H I J K L M N
    O P Q R S T U
    V W X Y Z
```

But the problem is that this loop is causing the last buttons in each row to be missing. So buttons G, N and U are missing. I want to know why are they missing and how can I fix the code below to show these buttons as well as the rest of the buttons.

```
    var i = 1;

    $('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $newBtn = '';
        if($this.is(':visible')){
            $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display: inline-block;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
        }else{
            $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display: none;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
        }

                    if(i % 7 == 0){
              $answer.append($newBtn+"<tr></tr>");
            }
            else
             $answer.append($newBtn);                 
            i = i+1;
        });




PHP CODE:


<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

    <table>
        <tr>

    <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($a as $key => $val){
            if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
            echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\" style=\"display: inline;\">";       
            if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hard to say without your HTML...  Maybe set `var i = 0`?

Comment: Letters H, P and X are missing if I do this if I do (i % 8 === 0)

Comment: @ T.J. I do want to append an empty row

Comment: please post your html. or better yet create a jsfiddle.

Comment: I wont be able to create fiddle because it retrieves a button from php code, I will post php code which displays the buttons on top correctly

Comment: @user1147294: You *can* create a minimal example, to post to the question (at least) and to http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com (optional). You may have to fudge the server-side bits, but that's hardly an insurmountable barrier.

Comment: var i = 0 causes the first buttons in the row to be missing. These buttons are A, H, O, V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ignore]

`$newBtn+"<tr></tr>"`
That's a jQuery instance + String.
I think that's where the problem lies.
Try keeping newBtn as a string all through until a final `$answer.append($(newBtn));`.

[/ignore]

I just tried building a single string and it turns out to be cumbersome.

The following solution is closer to your original intent, but avoids the trap of trying to append the invalid HTML fragment `"</tr><tr>"`:

```
var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if(i%7 == 0) {
        $row = $('<tr />').appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $('<td />').appendTo($row);
    }
    $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).appendTo($cell);
    i++;
});
```

`Tested only for synatax errors`

Comment: Do you know what I should change <tr><tr> to?

Comment: Further thoughts - string would ultimately be made to work but it's even easier to work with sequential appendTo()s, building table rows and their contents as you go. I will add to the answer above.